# Can I use Times New Roman in my web app without license?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I want to use Times New Roman (which has proprietary license) as main font of my commercial product (web app).

As it is pre-installed on most of the devices, I have no need to supply font files, so does it mean that I can avoid buying a license for this font and stay completely legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply specify Times New Roman in css, then no, no need to pay anything. You're not hosting a font file.

For hosting a font file, yes, sure, but in that case I recommend at least checking out alternatives such as STIX Two Text (open-source, based on 8pt TNR, better for small sizes), Liberation Serif (squarer design), [Tiempos](https://klim.co.nz/collections/tiempos/) (commercial, more styles and weights), [Times Eighteen](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/times-eighteen-font-linotype) (sharper, designed for headlines).

STIX Two Text for smaller text and TNR for larger sizes might be a good combination. If you're using serif fonts for both body text and headings, using optical sizes makes your layout look sharper. [Look here in the section on "progressive sizing"](https://www.typography.com/fonts/mercury-display/how-to-use) for a demonstration.